# How do I make bokeh omit missing dates when using datetime as x-axis

Tags: python, bokeh

I am looking at the candlestick example in the bokeh docs, found here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/candlestick.py

and I am trying to figure out a good way to eliminate the "spaces" in the x-axis where there is no data.

Specifically, for financial data like MSFT used in the example, there is no data for weekends and holidays.  Is there a way to tell bokeh not to leave an empty space in the chart when there is no data for a date?

Here is a paste of the example code found at the above link for convenience:

```
from math import pi
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT
from bokeh.plotting import *

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:50]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

mids = (df.open + df.close)/2
spans = abs(df.close-df.open)

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

output_file("candlestick.html", title="candlestick.py example")

figure(x_axis_type = "datetime", tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,previewsave",
   width=1000, name="candlestick")

hold()

segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color='black')
rect(df.date[inc], mids[inc], w, spans[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
rect(df.date[dec], mids[dec], w, spans[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

curplot().title = "MSFT Candlestick"
xaxis().major_label_orientation = pi/4
grid().grid_line_alpha=0.3

show()  # open a browser
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: As of Bokeh `0.12.6` you can specify overrides for major tick labels on axes.

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:50]
inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close

p = figure(plot_width=1000, title="MSFT Candlestick with Custom X-Axis")

# map dataframe indices to date strings and use as label overrides
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {
    i: date.strftime('%b %d') for i, date in enumerate(pd.to_datetime(df["date"]))
}

# use the *indices* for x-axis coordinates, overrides will print better labels
p.segment(df.index, df.high, df.index, df.low, color="black")
p.vbar(df.index[inc], 0.5, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df.index[dec], 0.5, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

output_file("custom_datetime_axis.html", title="custom_datetime_axis.py example")

show(p)
```

[image]

If you have a very large number of dates, this approach might become unwieldy, and a [Custom Extension](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) might become necessary.

Comment: Has there been any development on this request, or is there a known workaround?  In MPL you can use an integer based for the X axis and then apply custom labels so it appears to be a time series axis.

Comment: There is a new issue to add support for a "scaling" function to mappings so that e.g., overnight hours ould be "compressed" if there is not expected to be data. This is not quite the same thing as the broken axes described above, but it might be useful. Although, this sort of thing is definitely more useful for *times* than it is for *dates*. In general, calendering is a very hard problem.

Comment: Interesting, I am more interested in eliminating the weekend gap than overnight gap.  Many markets are open 24 hrs except the weekend.  Would the workaround mentioned above be possible in bokeh?  For example using integers as the X axis and using an array of date labels for display purposes.  In this case, if Friday was represented by x=6, then Monday's data would be represented by x=7.  If you had a pandas DF with the data of interest then simply calling df.reset_index() would create the contiguous "gap-free" integer index.

Comment: Say `df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:100]` and after that you had `df = df.drop(df.index[len(df.index) // 4:3 * len(df.index) // 4])` to remove the middle 50 (i.e. leave 25 at head and 25 at tail). This doesn't seem to be working, it leaves a gap of 50 and auto-fills it with numbers. Am I missing something or perhaps Bokeh 2.2.3 (the current version) doesn't work as it did before?

Comment: The approach here assumes and relies on the index being monotonically increasing integers with no gaps. You will need to re-index the `df` if you drop parts in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE 2016-05-26:

some details of the BokehJS interface have changed. For Bokeh `0.11` and newer, the `__implementation__` should now be:

```
__implementation__ = """
    _ = require "underscore"
    Model = require "model"
    p = require "core/properties"

    class DateGapTickFormatter extends Model
      type: 'DateGapTickFormatter'

      doFormat: (ticks) ->
        date_labels = @get("date_labels")
        return (date_labels[tick] ? "" for tick in ticks)

      @define {
        date_labels: [ p.Any ]
      }

    module.exports =
      Model: DateGapTickFormatter
"""
```

This is not expected to change any further.

#### 2016-02-09

[Pull request 3314](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/3314) was made for an example that works on 2015-12-05. [The original code is here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/3314/files). The documentation for the [candlestick example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/candlestick.html) is still showing the same code as the OP had in the question.

Included below for reference.

```
from math import pi

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models.formatters import TickFormatter, String, List

# In this custom TickFormatter, xaxis labels are taken from an array of date
# Strings (e.g. ['Sep 01', 'Sep 02', ...]) passed to the date_labels property. 
class DateGapTickFormatter(TickFormatter):
    date_labels = List(String)

    __implementation__ = """
_ = require "underscore"
HasProperties = require "common/has_properties"

class DateGapTickFormatter extends HasProperties
  type: 'DateGapTickFormatter'

  format: (ticks) ->
    date_labels = @get("date_labels")
    return (date_labels[tick] ? "" for tick in ticks)

module.exports =
  Model: DateGapTickFormatter
"""

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:50]

# xaxis date labels used in the custom TickFormatter
date_labels = [date.strftime('%b %d') for date in pd.to_datetime(df["date"])]

mids = (df.open + df.close)/2
spans = abs(df.close-df.open)

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 0.5

output_file("custom_datetime_axis.html", title="custom_datetime_axis.py example")

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p = figure(tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1000, toolbar_location="left")

# Using the custom TickFormatter. You must always define date_labels
p.xaxis[0].formatter = DateGapTickFormatter(date_labels = date_labels)

# x coordinates must be integers. If for example df.index are 
# datetimes, you should replace them with a integer sequence
p.segment(df.index, df.high, df.index, df.low, color="black")
p.rect(df.index[inc], mids[inc], w, spans[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.rect(df.index[dec], mids[dec], w, spans[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

p.title = "MSFT Candlestick with custom x axis"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4

p.grid[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 6

show(p)  # open a browser
```

---

Due to the code using the `dataframe` index, your data must be sorted in ascending date order. If you have a time series in descending date order it can be reversed for use by the above code with:

```
df.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```