# Bokeh autofill datetime axis missing values: how to stop it?

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh

I'm trying to build an interactive plot from a `pandas dataframe` of financial data. The dataframe index has some gap when market are closed, or during weekends. The problem is that Bokeh always autofill those gaps when I use the dataframe index as xasis, making it visually ugly.

[image: Example of Bokeh autofilling gaps in datetime axis.]

How can I print my data without gaps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373975/example-how-do-i-make-bokeh-omit-missing-dates-when-using-datetime-as-x-axis

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/t3HkalO4TGA

Comment: @greymatter if you can write it as a solution, I'll mark it as solved. Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert NaN between sections, Bokeh will not fill the gap:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 2, 3, np.nan, 10, 20], y=[1, 2, 3, np.nan, 3, 4]))
fig = figure(plot_height=250)
fig.line("x", "y", source=source)
show(fig)
```

the output:

[image]

Comment: I just don't want to see that white space, nor a strict line connecting the last value of day n with the first value of day n+1.To keep it simple, I want the two lines connected. In my index I don't have datetime values for when the markets are closed, or weekends or holidays, but it's like Bokeh automatically creates them just to connect the y value of the last day that I have, with the first y value of the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the repo that plots candlesticks without gaps. You will have to use the integer index of the points as your x-axis, then use a custom tick formatter, or tick overrides to display those as the correct dates:

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:51]
inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close

p = figure(plot_width=1000, title="MSFT Candlestick with Custom X-Axis")

# map dataframe indices to date strings and use as label overrides
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {
    i: date.strftime('%b %d') for i, date in enumerate(pd.to_datetime(df["date"]))
}
p.xaxis.bounds = (0, df.index[-1])
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.05

p.segment(df.index, df.high, df.index, df.low, color="black")
p.vbar(df.index[inc], 0.5, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df.index[dec], 0.5, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

output_file("custom_datetime_axis.html", title="custom_datetime_axis.py example")

show(p)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without doing label overrides? I am trying to achieve this along with using RELATIVE_DATETIME_CONTEXT, to format my ticks nicely. I haven't been able to figure out how it can be done. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have any suggestions offhand. The built-in context formatters are only designed to work with actual, proper datetime axes (i.e. where the values are datetime timestamps). This is not that at all, the axis is just a integer index into a subsetted list of date strings to "skip" the missing dates. You best bet is probably to look at a [`CustomJSTickFormatter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.CustomJSTickFormatter)

Comment: Okay. This is my understanding(I am new to Bokeh): Ticker is used for telling the positions of the ticks, and TickFormatter is used to get a representation of each tick label. DatetimeTicker is a composite ticker and uses different tickers for different resolutions. And DatetimeTickFormatter gives tick labels based on tick and resolution.  -- continued...

Comment: Now I want to keep using the DatetimeTickFormatter, but I don't want to use DatetimeTicker to use continuous tickers(DayTicker, MonthTicker, etc). So can I replace the DatetimeTicker with my own custom CompsiteTicker which will have my own defined DaysTicker, while using DatetimeTickFormatter as it is?

Comment: Since this is an extended and conceptual discussion, it would probably be better to move to the Bokeh Discourse: https://discourse.bokeh.org/