# Bokeh - Fill the gap in line plot (standalone)

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm looking to fill the gap in this plot:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'YYYY_MM': {0: '2020-11',
  1: '2020-12',
  2: '2021-01',
  3: '2021-02',
  4: '2021-03'},
 'value': {0: 0.7,
  1: np.nan,
  2: 0.5,
  3: 0.8,
  4: 0.2}})

factors = data["YYYY_MM"].tolist()
p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*factors), 
           plot_height=350)

p.line(x="YYYY_MM", 
       y="value", 
       source = data,
       color="orange",
       line_width=2,
      legend_label="legend")


p.circle(x="YYYY_MM", 
       y="value", 
       source = data,
       color="orange",
      legend_label="legend")

show(p)
```

[image]

How can I put a line between the dot and the line? How can I do that the line plot ignore the missing value? I have found some examples when bokeh does automatically what I'm looking for ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528519/bokeh-autofill-datetime-axis-missing-values-how-to-stop-it)) but it seems for the line plot it doesn't do it automatically. So, how can do I solve this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked question is not relevant. That concerns compressing an axis to omit certain values (e.g. non-trading days) so that what is left is "closer together". That has no relation to wanting to keep the full axis, but ignore `nan` values in the data.

You have to remove the `nan` value from your data before passing it to Bokeh, there is no other way. Bokeh will always interrupt rendering for nan values (that behavior is intentional). You might consider pandas [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna) method to get a view of the dataframe with all nan values removed that you can pass to Bokeh.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I understand. But i cannot drop the nan as I can't drop the date, because I have more data (for example, the real plot also have vertical bars where its data comes from other columns like 'values' in this example, and are plotted with the date). If I replace the nan with 0, the plot is awful.

Comment: I didn't say to replace the nans with zeros, I said to drop them entirely. It's possible you will need seperate data sources for different glyphs then, one with the nans and another without for the line. Bokeh will alway split lines on nans, there is no way to change that.