# How to remove not added datetime from the patches plot

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

I using `bokeh` patchs plot for my energy datas. It successfully worked the default timeseries. But if I select different two dates then it merges two date ranges block

**Example:**
date-range : `29/07/2018 - 31/07/2018 with hours`

[Successfull working example of result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3aoC.png)

dates : `30/07/2018 and 06/08/2018 with hours`

[Wrongly working example of result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz1ej.jpg)

So I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893822/when-plotting-a-graph-using-bokeh-how-to-remove-missing-date-while-x-axis-type) post but it's not change anything.

And code blocks :

```
df = generateRtpDataFrame(data_list,frekans)
df=df.round(2)
def stacked(df):
    df=df[df.columns[::-1]]
    df_top = df.cumsum(axis=1)     
    df_bottom = df_top.shift(axis=1).fillna({'total': 0})[::-1]        
    df_stack = pd.concat([df_bottom, df_top], ignore_index=False)
    df_stack=df_stack.drop("total", axis=1)
    return df_stack
areas = stacked(df)
colors = d3['Category20b'][areas.shape[1]]

x2 = np.hstack((df.index[::-1], df.index))   
msg = "Example Plot"     
caption = Title(text=msg, align='left', text_font_size='10pt')
tooltips=[
    ("index", "$index"),          
]
p = figure(sizing_mode = 'scale_width',tooltips=tooltips,x_axis_type='datetime')           
p.add_layout(caption, 'above')    
p.grid.minor_grid_line_color = '#eeeeee'
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
    minutes=["%M"],
    hours=["%H:%M"],
    days=["%d/%m/%Y"],
    months=["%m/%Y"],
    years=["%Y"],
)

p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {
    i: date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for i, date in enumerate(pd.to_datetime(df.index))
}        
p.patches(xs=[x2]*areas.shape[1],ys= [areas[c].values for c in areas], color=colors, alpha=0.8,line_color=None)
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to help. What does "select different dates" mean? All that can be said at the moment is that if you want the "left"and "right" patches separated, *you* will have to create separate patches to make that happen. If you make one patch that happens to have of distance between two points, Bokeh will not care, they will be connected because that is what a patch is for, connecting regions.